# laravel check if the model's filed is empty or not

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model's field like this:

```
$xmlDocument->masterInformation->nextPage->prefix
```

this field is not required.

I want to check if that field is empty or not

I do this:

```
if(trim($xmlDocument->masterInformation->nextPage->prefix)){
            $data['NextPage']['prefix'] = $xmlDocument->masterInformation->nextPage->prefix;
        }
```

but the `if` statement is never becomming true though when I `echo` that field, i got data.

what am i missing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update like this,

```
if(trim($xmlDocument->masterInformation->nextPage->prefix) != '')
```

Comment: I just tried your solution and still the if statment is not firing, but the else statement is firing

Comment: no no sorry the if statement is firing now, but the `prefix` entry in the array is not showing, why please? do you want more code?

Comment: now I found the problem +1 I will accept your answer when the system allows, many thanks